# KeyFactory.stringToKey() consistently gives "IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse Reference"

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have made a little Google App Engine program which suddenly gives exceptions that I don't understand. Running this program locally, I'm trying to use the method of the Google App Engine SDK *stringToKey()* of the *KeyFactory* class on a number of strings, which however consistently gives me an error.

Examples:

```
KeyFactory.stringToKey("randomstring");
```

Both lines of code give me the following IllegalArgumentException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse Reference
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.stringToKey(KeyFactory.java:203)
at com.businessLayer.DDOSLogAnalyser.handleUsersSet(DDOSLogAnalyser.java:81)
at com.businessLayer.DDOSLogAnalyser.doPost(DDOSLogAnalyser.java:50)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[...]
```

With DDOSLogAnalyser the only class I have coded myself. The class extends HttpServlet superclass. If any more information is needed, I can gladly provide it.

Comment: Visit below likn, that might prove useful https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"randomstring" is not a valid key string. I believe a valid key string should be formated like this:

```
Key([Key("ancestorKindName", idOrName),] "kindName", idOrName)
```

Note that the `stringToKey` method is not intended to create keys in the way of allocation. If you are looking for such a functionality, look for `DatastoreService.allocateIds()` in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities).